# Is it possible to use conditional statements such as if/then/when like this in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that has an id field - think of it as a foreign key. I need to make a desicion based on the value of this id field such that:

- If the value is less then 3100, run a nested fetch from table B.
- If the value is greater then 3100, run a nested fetch from a table C.

The statement looks like this:

```
Select a.ID, a.SN, a.User_Ident,
    (select b.first_name from b where b.ident = a.User_Ident) as 'First Name',
    (select b.last_name from b where b.ident = a.User_Ident) as 'Last Name',
from a
where ...
```

What I would like to accomplish is something like this:

```
Select a.ID, a.SN, a.User_Ident,
   when a.User_Ident > 3100 then
       (select b.first_name from b where b.ident = a.User_Ident) as 'First Name',
       (select b.last_name from b where b.ident = a.User_Ident) as 'Last Name'
   else 
       (select c.name from c where c.ident = a.User_Ident) as 'Name'
from a
where ....
```

Is this possible?

UPDATE: Your answers suggested I use left joins. My query already contains several left outer joins, so I don't know how this would work. Here is the complete query:

```
select    
A.Ident,
A.Serial_Number,
A.Category_Ident,
C.Description as Category,
A.Purchase_Order,
A.Manufacturer_Ident,
M.Description as Manufacturer,    
A.Hardware_Model,
A.Processor_Quantity,
A.Processor_Speed_Hertz,
A.Memory_Installed_Bytes,
A.Memory_Maximum_Bytes,
A.Memory_Slots_Used,
A.Memory_Slots_Total,
A.Storage_Capacity_Bytes,
A.Video_Memory_Bytes,
A.Screen_Size_Diagonal_Inches,    
A.Software_Ident,
S.Software_Title,    
A.Account_Ident,
T.Description as Account,

A.User_Ident,
(select Q.dbo.P.user_name from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident) as 'User Name',
(select Q.dbo.P.first_name from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident) as 'First Name',
(select Q.dbo.P.last_name from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident) as 'Last Name',
(select Q.dbo.R.description from Q.dbo.R where Q.dbo.R.ident =  (select Q.dbo.P.rank from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident)) as 'Rank',
(select Q.dbo.P.phone from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident) as 'Phone',
(select Q.dbo.P.smtp_address from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident) as 'Email',
(select Q.dbo.O.description from Q.dbo.O where Q.dbo.O.ident =  (select Q.dbo.P.organization_ident from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident)) as 'Organization',
(select Q.dbo.L.description from Q.dbo.L where Q.dbo.L.ident =  (select Q.dbo.P.location_ident from Q.dbo.P where Q.dbo.P.ident = A.User_Ident)) as 'Location',

A.Disposition_Ident,
D.Description as Disposition,
A.Notes,
A.Updated,
A.UpdatedBy,
A.Label,
A.Scanned,
S.Licensed

FROM Assets 

left outer join C on A.Category_Ident = C.Ident
left outer join M on A.Manufacturer_Ident = M.Ident
left outer join S on A.Software_Ident = S.Ident
left outer join T on A.Account_Ident = T.Ident
left outer join D on A.Disposition_Ident = D.Ident

WHERE ((T.Description like '%' +  @Account + '%') or (A.Account_Ident like '%' +  @Account + '%'))

order by Serial_Number
```

Comment: btw, what flavour SQL are we talking here...SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to skin a cat, but I think this approach is worth a try, using a UNION to combine the results of the 2 different conditions (1 query joined to b for ids > 3100, and another query joined to c for ids <= 3100).

You have to return the same fields (you can't as you indicated you wanted), return 1 "name" field when looking at c when you return 2 fields for the b condition. Hence, in this example, when you join to c, it returns "name" as First Name, and returns a blank Last Name value.

```
Select a.ID, a.SN, a.User_Ident, b.first_name AS 'First Name', b.last_name AS 'Last Name'
FROM a
    JOIN b ON a.User_Ident = b.ident
WHERE (a.User_Ident > 3100)
   AND (......)
UNION ALL
Select a.ID, a.SN, a.User_Ident, c.name AS 'First Name', '' AS 'Last Name'
FROM a
    JOIN c ON a.User_Ident = c.ident
WHERE (a.User_Ident <= 3100)
   AND (......)
```

Comment: Then you don't know when you have a `First Name` or a `Name`, that sounds like valuable information you're losing.

Comment: Yep true. You could just return First Name, Last Name and Name - the first and last fields would be blank from the c part, and the Name field would be blank from the b part. Was just outlining the kind of approach

Answer (score 1):

I'd accomplish this with two left joins and a case statement:

```
select  a.field1, 
        case when b.lastname is not null then b.firstname else c.firstname end,
        case when b.lastname is not null then b.lastname else c.larstname end
from table1 a 
left join table2 b 
    on a.id = b.id
left join table3 c 
    on a.id = c.id
```

Note I used lastname is null filed in both case staments, becasue tyou probably don;t want the first name form one table and the last name form the other and lastname is less likely to be null than the firstname in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

CASE can only return a column, not a row, and you can't correlate queries into it afaik. And no matter what, a result set must have a static amount of columns.

I think what you would want would be a result set where if the `First Name` or `Last Name` was filled out the Name was `null`.

```
a.ID | a.SN | Name | First Name | Last Name
1    | #    | Name | null       | null
2    | #    | null | John       | Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Union would work(beat me there), or you could use an inline function as well. Like the others have said you must return same set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on HLGEM's answer

```
select  a.field1, 
        case when b.lastname is not null then b.firstname else c.firstname end,
        case when b.lastname is not null then b.lastname else c.larstname end
from table1 a 
left join table2 b 
    on a.User_Ident > 3100 AND a.id = b.id
left join table3 c 
    on a.User_Ident <= 3100 AND a.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on the outer join solution is:

```
SELECT
   a.id
  ,a.ssn
  ,a.user_ident
  ,case when a.user_ident <= 3100 then c.name else b.lastname end   LastName
  ,case when a.user_ident <= 3100 then ''     else b.firstname end  FirstName
 from a
  left outer join b
   on b.ident = a.user_ident
  left outer join c
   on c.ident = a.user_ident
```

A query cannot vary the number of columns returned (at least not in any system I'm familiar with), so if you have a "case C" situation and only have Name, I would return it as LastName and set FirstName to the empty string. This could be made a NULL, if that fits your application better.